# Create Bat file from a bat file in a specified format

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Can someone please help me out?
Currently, I've got this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%
```

Now, I need to create a `abcd.bat` file (from this .bat file) that will contain a line in below format:

```
abcy.exe -c %ip% -i2 -u -b 45M -p5600 -t 200 -B 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: If a solution to your question has been provided, please follow site protocol and mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your snippet:

```bat
echo abcy.exe -c %ip% -i2 -u -b 45M -p5600 -t 200 -B 1.2.3.4 > new.bat
```

Comment: @Stephan Question was edited after my answer. Mine works, works as it was understood according to original question. Now I've fix the answer according to updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```bat
@Set "ts=@abcy.exe -c%%ip%% -i2 -u -b 45M -p5600 -t 200 -B 1.2.3.4"
@For /F "Tokens=2Delims=:" %%A In ('IPConfig^|Find "IPv4"') Do @Set "ip=%%A"
@(Call Echo %ts%)>"abcd.bat"
```

*I've assigned your output to a variable, `%ts%`, on the first line so that you can easily adjust the output text string, (just leave `%%ip%%`, which has a leading space, alone).*